# How to deploy a PyCharm project with Kivy and mapview?

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, kivy-language

I want to deploy a Python Project with Kivy and a MapView. I develop with PyCharm and when I run my project with it, everything works well.
I also tried to compile and run my project with the python IDLE, it also works good !

I followed the instructions of PyInstaller (https://www.pyinstaller.org/#pyinstaller-quickstart) and the folders were created. The problem is that my .exe file doesn't works... A cmd window is opened but it's immediately closed..

If you need more explanation, just let me know :) thanks !

Comment: By default, `PyInstaller` creates a one-folder bundle. That means that the `.exe` file that is produced does not contain everything needed to run the `App`, but the needed components should be in the created folder. You should have a look at the detailed instructions for running `PyInstaller`. According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.garden.html#packaging), you may need to install `mapview` using `garden install --app mapview` in your app directory.

Comment: Hello, I already tried it but it still doesn't work..
Maybe I'm doing it wrong? Here's how I did it: My project directory (the one containing the .py , .kv files and other files created by PyCharm) is named FinderPython. If I understand correctly, the app directory created by PyInstaller is FinderPython/dist

In "dist" file, I opened CMD and typed : garden install --app mapview

I have this result in CMD "Done! garden.mapview is installed at: C:\Users\Esref\Documents\Proj_Finder\Proj_Finder\DirFinderPython\dist\libs\garden\garden.mapview
Cleaning...

But my .exe still not works... :(

Comment: No, as I understand it, you should be in the `FinderPython` directory when you run the `garden install --app mapview`, then run `PyInstaller`.

Comment: I tried as you said but it still not work.. Here's a screenshot I was able to get during the split second CMD prompt was displayed with errors, I don't know if it can help : [CMD PROMPT](https://ibb.co/0jsWR1p)

Comment: I wrote a little `App` using `MapView` and tried to create an `exe` using `PyInstaller` as I described above. It didn't work. The only way I could get it to work was to do the `garden install --app mapview`, and then move the `mapiew` folder (the one that actually contains the mapview python files) up to make it a subfolder of my app folder. Then I changed my `import` statement to `from mapview import MapView, MapMarker`. After that `Pyinstaller` made an `exe` that worked. Looks like a bug in either `kivy` or `pyinstaller`.

Comment: Okay, I see, do you have any video or something like that because I don't really understand how to do..
I'm still going to try with what I've been able to figure out

Comment: Ok, I tried like you, but this time, I've got this [error](https://ibb.co/7gTNhGj) 
"[INFO          ] [Text         ] Provider: sdl2
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort." I don't really find how to resolve it..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `main.py`:

```
from mapview import MapView, MapMarker
from kivy.app import App

class MapViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        map = MapView(zoom=15, lat=39.566848, lon=-76.377053, double_tap_zoom=True)
        marker_1 = MapMarker(lat=39.566848, lon=-76.377053, source='marker.png')
        map.add_marker(marker_1)
        return map

MapViewApp().run()
```

And my `main.spec` file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\PyCharmProjects\\MapViewPlay'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('marker.png', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

And my directory structure:

```
-MapViewPlay

    main.py

    main.spec

    -mapview

        __init__.py

        types.py

        utils.py

        .

        .

        .
```

The `mapview` folder above is the `garden\garden.mapview\mapview` folder (installed using `garden install --app mapview`) just copied there and the rest of the `garden` folder removed. I consider this a hack. You shouldn't have to do it this way, but doing it the recommended way does not work. I run `pyinstaller` as `pyinstaller main.spec`.

Comment: I answered your comment earlier, so I did as you explain here, but it still doesn't work :/...
You can refer to my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107233/how-to-deploy-a-pycharm-project-with-kivy-and-mapview/63145074#comment111661836_63107233).
I copied and pasted your Python script, I ran it with the Python IDLE, taking care to add the "mapview" folder and it works.
However, when I deploy the project with the "pyinstall main.py" command, the .exe file still doesn't work, and I get the same error as before...

Comment: I think that error is a different issue. I have never experienced that problem and have no idea how to fix it. But have a look at [this](https://kivy.readthedocs.io/en/master/faq.html#unable-to-get-a-window-abort).

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll open a new topic for this error. I checked the FAQ but I think that's for running errors and not deploying errors :/